# Error Msg 156: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Order'

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ddl, create-table

```
CREATE TABLE Store(
StoreID int NOT NULL UNIQUE,
      StoreName  varchar NOT NULL,
ManagerFirstName varchar NOT NULL,
ManagerLastName varchar NOT NULL,
Phone int NOT NULL,
      Email varchar NOT NULL
    CONSTRAINT StorePK PRIMARY KEY (StoreID),
CONSTRAINT StoreAK1 UNIQUE(Email)
);

CREATE TABLE Product(
ProductID int NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    ProductName varchar NOT NULL,
    ProductType varchar NOT NULL,
    ListPrice  money NOT NULL,
    Size    int NOT NULL
    CONSTRAINT ProductPK PRIMARY KEY (ProductID)
);
CREATE TABLE Customer(
CustomerID int NOT NULL UNIQUE,
      FirstName  varchar NOT NULL,
LastName varchar NOT NULL,
      Email varchar NOT NULL,
      Phone int NOT NULL,
      Address varchar NOT NULL

CONSTRAINT CUSTOMERPK PRIMARY KEY (CustomerID),
CONSTRAINT CUSTOMERAK1 UNIQUE(Email)
);


CREATE TABLE Suppliers(
SupplierID int NOT NULL UNIQUE,
      CompanyName varchar NOT NULL,
FirstName  varchar NOT NULL,
LastName varchar NOT NULL,
      Phone int NOT NULL,
      Email varchar NOT NULL,

CONSTRAINT SuppliersPK PRIMARY KEY (SupplierID),
CONSTRAINT CUSTOMERAK1 UNIQUE(Email)
);


CREATE TABLE Order (
OrderID int NOT NULL UNIQUE,
CustomerID int NOT NULL UNIQUE,
EmployeeID int NOT NULL UNIQUE,
OrderDate DATE NOT NULL,
TotalCost money NOT NULL
   CONSTRAINT OrderPK PRIMARY KEY (OrderID,CustomerID,EmployeeID),
         CONSTRAINT OrderFK FOREIGN KEY (CustomerID)
   REFERENCES Customer(CustomerID),
   CONSTRAINT OrderFK1 FOREIGN KEY (EmployeeID)
   REFERENCES Employee(EmployeeID)
);

CREATE TABLE OrderLine(
OrderID int NOT NULL UNIQUE,
ProductID int NOT NULL UNIQUE,
LineNumber int NOT NULL,
Quantity int NOT NULL,
UnitPrice money NOT NULL,
ExtenderPrice money NOT NULL
CONSTRAINT OrderLinePK PRIMARY KEY (OrderID,ProductID),
    CONSTRAINT OrderLineFK FOREIGN KEY (OrderID)
REFERENCES Order (OrderID),
CONSTRAINT OrderLineFK1 FOREIGN KEY (ProductID)
REFERENCES Product(ProductID)
);

CREATE TABLE Employee(
EmployeeID int NOT NULL UNIQUE,
FirstName  varchar NOT NULL,
LastName varchar NOT NULL,
StoreID int NOT NULL UNIQUE,
HireDate DATE NOT NULL,
Phone int NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT EmployeePK PRIMARY KEY (EmployeeID),
CONSTRAINT EmployeeFK FOREIGN KEY (StoreID)
REFERENCES Store(StoreID)


);
CREATE TABLE Inventory(
InventoryID int NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    ProductID int NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    StoreID int NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    QuantityOnHand int NOT NULL
        CONSTRAINT InventoryPK PRIMARY KEY (InventoryID),
        CONSTRAINT InventoryFK FOREIGN KEY (ProductID)
        REFERENCES Product(ProductID),
        CONSTRAINT InventoryFK1 FOREIGN KEY(StoreID)
        REFERENCES Store(StoreID)
);
CREATE TABLE Quotes(
SupplierID int NOT NULL UNIQUE,
ProductID int NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    Quote money NOT NULL,
    QuoteDate DATE NOT NULL
        CONSTRAINT QuotesPK PRIMARY KEY (SupplierID,ProductID)
        CONSTRAINT QuotesFK FOREIGN KEY (SupplierID)
        REFERENCES Suppliers(SupplierID),
        CONSTRAINT QuotesFK1 FOREIGN KEY (ProductID)
        REFERENCES Product(ProductID)
);`
```

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 46
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Order'.
>   Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 67
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Order'.

Code won't process, not sure why.

Comment: There is a code formatting option `{}` in the question editor ([edit]) - please use it.

Comment: And please actually ask a question... not just dump code and an error.

Comment: `order` is a reserved keyword, you need to quote it `"Order"`

Comment: Another note on naming conventions. There are strong feelings on both sides of this, but whether you name your tables in the singular or the plural (`Invoice` vs. `Invoices`), you should be internally consistent.

Comment: Thank You it ran successful! Thanks again and appreciate everyone helping me!

Answer (score 0):

`Order` is a reserved word in most RDBMS. If you want to use it as an table or column name, you need to surround it with square brackets; but better yet, avoid using reserved names. Here, you could use `Orders` instead.

Another problem is that you have two constraints name `CUSTOMERAK1`. I think the second occurence should be named `SuppliersAK1`.

Also, table `Employee` must be declared *before* table `Orders`, which references it.

With this changes, **[your code runs fine](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=80c3b6f73f57187b06bb3c685a067bd9)**.